# Display commas in javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display some set values for my stats on the webpage....

The javascript is:

```
<script src="****/js/waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  $.fn.waypoint.defaults = {
     context: window,
     continuous: false,
     enabled: true,
     horizontal: false,
     offset: 0,
     triggerOnce: true
  }

$('.facts_waypoint').waypoint(function(direction) {  
function count($this){
    var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
    if (current >= 1000000) {current = current +493023;}
    else if (current >= 10000) {current = current +43749;}
    else if (current >= 1000) { current = current + 7369;}
    else { if (current >= 100) { current = current + 197;}
            else {current = current + 1}
    }
    /*current = current + 100;  Where 1 is increment */

    $this.html(++current);
    if(current > $this.data('count')){
        $this.html($this.data('count'));
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){count($this)}, 50);
    }
}
jQuery(".count_one, .count_two, .count_three").each(function() {
  jQuery(this).data('count', parseInt(jQuery(this).html(), 10));
  jQuery(this).html('0');
  count(jQuery(this));
});
});
```

However, it only displays the first numbers before the commas... I.e. 22,256,244 = 22 will be displayed... So I tried using LocalString:

```
<script>
   var number = 22874098;
   number.toLocaleString(); // "22,874,098"
</script>
```

This failed and just kept increasing..... Also no commas were included.

Can anyone shed any light on how I would get the numbers to stop increasing BUT more importantly - show commas?

Cheers for now!

Edit - Just tried this:

```
    <script>
      $.fn.waypoint.defaults = {
  context: window,
  continuous: false,
  enabled: true,
  horizontal: false,
  offset: 0,
  triggerOnce: true
}

$('.facts_waypoint').waypoint(function(direction) {  
function count($this){
    var current = parseInt($this.text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''), 10);
    if (current >= 1000000) {current = current +493023;}
    else if (current >= 10000) {current = current +43749;}
    else if (current >= 1000) { current = current + 7369;}
    else { if (current >= 100) { current = current + 197;}
            else {current = current + 1}
    }
    /*current = current + 100;  Where 1 is increment */

    $this.text(++current);
    if(current > $this.data('count')){
        $this.text($this.data('count'));
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){count($this)}, 50);
    }
}
jQuery(".count_one, .count_two, .count_three").each(function() {
  jQuery(this).data('count', parseInt(jQuery(this).text(), 10));
  jQuery(this).text('0');
  count(jQuery(this));
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the comma issue, you will need to strip out non-numeric characters from the value before doing the parseInt. I suggest using `$this.text()` as opposed to `$this.html()` and using a regular expression on the input.

```
var current = parseInt($this.text().replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
```

That will replace only the commas from the input with empty strings leaving you the digits and the decimal separator. Since you are only interested in integers, you can take another approach with the regular expression and remove all non-numeric characters.

```
var current = parseInt($this.text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''), 10);
```

When parsing or formatting the value of the field you need to strip out or add commas and carry the `text()` or `html()` call through the whole code path. I went through the code and adjusted a couple of things to make it a bit more readable and separate out the parsing more clearly. Give the following a try:

```
$('.facts_waypoint').waypoint(function(direction) {  
    function parse(text) {
        return parseInt(text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''), 10);
    }

    function count($this) {
        var current = parse($this.text());
        if (current >= 1000000) {
            current = current + 493023;
        } else if (current >= 10000) {
            current = current + 43749;
        } else if (current >= 1000) { 
            current = current + 7369;
        } else if (current >= 100) { 
            current = current + 197;
        } else {
            current = current + 1;
        }

        $this.text((++current).toLocaleString());
        if (current < $this.data('count')) {
            setTimeout(function() { 
                count($this) 
            }, 50);
        }
    }

    jQuery(".count_one, .count_two, .count_three").each(function() {  
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        $this.data('count', parse($this.text()));
        $this.text('0');
        count($this);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey - many many many thanks for the reply and taking the time to help... I tried replace .html to .text - however it's still occurring: https://volocommerce.com